# Preserve original terms when using a thesaurus

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search, postgresql-9.3

The docs at www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/textsearch-dictionaries.html state:

> Basically a thesaurus dictionary replaces all non-preferred terms by one preferred term and, optionally, preserves the original terms for indexing as well.

However I do not see any options for enabling the preservation of the original terms.

For instance:

```
# SELECT to_tsvector('supernovae stars');
 to_tsvector 
-------------
 'sn':1
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "option" consists of replicating the original terms in the thesaurus.

This is mentioned in the doc you [linked](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/textsearch-dictionaries.html) if you read further down the page in **Thesaurus Example**:

> To index the original phrase as well as the substitute, just include
>   it in the right-hand part of the definition:

Thesaurus entry:

```
 supernovae stars : sn supernovae stars
```

Result:

```
 SELECT plainto_tsquery('supernova star');
        plainto_tsquery
 -----------------------------
  'sn' & 'supernova' & 'star'
```